# Xpages Rich Text field formatted in email

Tags: xpages

I have an Xpage where a button fires an email dialog. I have a rich text control. Now when I enter some text in the rich text control and format the font color to "Red" . When I send the email, I noted in the receiving end that the font color is not "Red". It is "Black" in color. The code behind the send button creates a temporary "memo" backend Notes document and gets all the information from the front end. The Rich text control content is retrieved as MIME and then converted into RT. I actually save the backend notes document after converting to RT. I found this is the reason end user does not get the message in desired color. But I have to save the backend document to attach(embed) files into the rich text. Can some one please say why this happens ? and any solution or ideas for this ?

Comment: Please add some code to show us how you retrieve the field contents as MIME and convert it into RT.

Comment: code rulez, follow Fredrik's advice

Comment: I agree.  You can send MIME emails using SSJS, so why bother converting to RT?  Just send the MIME.

Answer (score 3):

Use one of this ways to send html emails instead

http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=create-html-mails-in-ssjs-using-mime

or

http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=emailbean-send-dominodocument-html-emails-cw-embedded-images-attachments-custom-headerfooter
When you send HTML emails

I think you will get a better result then.